# Dollars and Envelopes

Tags: mathematics, counting

*Credit to [CarTalk](https://t.e2ma.net/message/fjehq/zuwusab)*

---

Imagine I'm going to give you one thousand dollars, in one-dollar bills. Your job is to put some of those dollar bills in the envelopes, in such a manner that no matter what number of dollars I ask you for you'll hand me the appropriate combination of envelopes.

The question is

## What's the smallest number of envelopes, and how much money do you put in each one?

Comment: Yes, I stole this one - credit to original given in question source.

Comment: I made the given credits visible.

Comment: Usually when I credit a source I like to leave it as an html comment so that people can't as easily just go to the website and steal the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer:

> I think binary (with a slight modification for the last envelope) solves this for 10 envelopes max. The envelopes you need contain 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 489 bills.

Method:

> First lay the above envelopes down in reverse order (starting with 489 on the left then reaching 1 on the right).
> If the amount asked for is smaller than or equal to 511 then:
> Convert that number to binary. Then write the corresponding digits in binary underneath those envelopes (one per envelope), and align the number to the right. Take those envelopes which have a 1 (in binary) under them.
>  Else, if that number is greater than 511, then take the 489 envelope, and subtract 489 from that number. Then convert that number to binary and execute the steps above.

Comment: Thing is, for that to work, off binary, you'd need 1024 dollar bills. You have exactly 1000 bills...

Comment: Oh yeah - you're right. I'll rethink it. Shall I delete this answer for now, or leave it as an idea?

Comment: actually you need 1023 bills to work.

Comment: Marius - valid point. I was just rushing my comment to avoid Question Asker devoting too much time to an incorrect answer.

Comment: I think if I reduce the 512 one by 23, it would work?

Comment: Yup that does work. It's also the solution you can find elsewhere online for this :) (didn't want to run away with it :p)

Comment: Ah I see. I think I'll leave my answer as is without explanation of why it works as Marius has done that, although I'll explain how to do it.

Comment: A follow up question could be: how many other arrangements of 10 bills exist? (for example reduce the 256 to 255, and put the bill into the 490 envelope)

Comment: Perhaps another interesting extension to this question were if an envelope you take can be subtracted from the total amount you are trying to reach instead of being added to it. (You would need another real life situation instead of money for it to make sense)

Comment: This one's the first - congrats.

Comment: @QuestionAsker, you can actually do it with money: just say both seller and buyer have the same amount of envelopes, and that buyer has to pay for merchandise while possibly receiving some change. If you haven't seen the answer to that one yet, it's surprisingly similar to the answer to this one!

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> 10 envelopes

How?

> 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 489

Why?

> All the numbers are powers of 2 (except the last one).
>  Let's take envelope $n\leq8$. You can form any amount up to $2^n$ by the envelopes $1$ to $n$.
>  Then you can get the amount $2^{n+1}$ from envelope n then start over.
>  the trick is with envelope $10$.
>  You can get any amount up to $511$ from envelopes $1$ to $9$.
>  For amounts from $512$ to $1000$ you just need to take envelope $10$ and the rest will be below 511 so you can still get them from the other envelopes.
>  side effect, you can get the amounts from $489$ to $511$ in 2 ways.

Comment: 6 isn't a power of 2

Comment: @StephenTG. Sorry. Typo. My brain hears 2,4 automatically says 6.

Comment: @Marius Mine hears 2, 4, and automatically says 8.  Maybe I've been programming too much.

Answer (score 2):

Following the approach of the other answers, I particularly like the following values.

> 500, 250, 125, 63, 31, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

Process the envelopes starting with the highest value. Hand over each envelope whose value is not greater than the balance owing.

Comment: Interesting... Those are almost identical to the available shutter speeds on an "analog" camera...

Comment: Hmmmm, interesting.  I would accept this as another correct answer - albeit it's not the one I've been looking for...